# Netty server sometimes lose data

Tags: java, xml, json, netty

I work on client-server application with flash client and Netty 4.0.24 server. Client communicates with server via XMLSocket. Data is JSON. All work correct. But when i start some stress-test to server, data sometimes lose. JSON Parser throws the exception.
My server pipelne is:

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline=channel.pipeline();
pispeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.nulDelimiter()));
pipeline.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG));
pipeline.addLast("EchoHandler", new EchoPipe());
```

at EchoPipe class

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws ParseException {
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    String data =in.toString(io.netty.util.CharsetUtil.UTF_8); 
    DataProcessor.parser.reset();
    try{
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)DataProcessor.parser.parse(data.toString());                        
   ...
    } catch(ParseException ex){
       System.out.println(ex.toString());
       System.out.println("err_message: "+data);
    }
```

Sometimes server catch the ParseException. On similar data. This appears when i start about 10 client connections, sending the test packets 3 time a second...

The stacktrace of the exception:

```
Unexpected token VALUE(viewer_type) at position 834.
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:146)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
at frusrv.EchoPipe.channelRead(EchoPipe.java:52)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:283)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:161)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Another time the stacktrace is:

```
Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 834.
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:146)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
at frusrv.EchoPipe.channelRead(EchoPipe.java:52)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:283)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:161)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: A good starting point would be to include the exception, and also some input/expected output data when this exception occurs.

Comment: the exception is: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 834, or sometimes Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 834. But i always sent the similar data to server, the identical data

Comment: Please include the stacktrace when you get the exception.